# RabbitMQ direct reply to. I'm getting the AlreadyClosedException

Tags: java, rabbitmq

SOLVED: Move the

> channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE, props, message.getBytes());

below

> channel.basicConsume(replyQueue, ...)

That fixed the issue.

---

I'm trying to figure out how to use the RabbitMQ direct reply-to feature. Since the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) is rather vague on how to implement it, I tried to use the [RPC](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html) example, adopting it to use direct reply-to instead.

```
private final static String QUEUE = "Test_chan";
private void directReplyToClient(ConnectionFactory factory) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    String replyQueue;

    try {
        connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();

        //replyQueue = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        replyQueue = "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to";
        AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties
                .Builder()
                .replyTo(replyQueue)
                .build();
        String message = "Hello World";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE, props, message.getBytes());

        final BlockingQueue<String> response = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

        channel.basicConsume(replyQueue, true, new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

                response.offer(new String(body, "UTF-8"));

            }
        });

        System.out.println(response.take());

    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (channel != null)
                channel.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException _ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Setting reply address to

> channel.queueDeclare().getQueue()

works, but setting it to

> amq.rabbitmq.reply-to

gives the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException:
>   channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method:
>   method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist, class-id=60, method-id=40)

Does anyone see where I'm doing something wrong? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Just realised that the exception is from me trying to close the channel at the bottom. So I'm trying to close an already closed channel. Why is it already closed then?

Comment: I figured it out all the sudden. Just move the basicPublish call below the basicConsume call, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

So this is the code for the solution. Do a consume before a publish.

```
private final static String QUEUE = "Test_chan";

private void directReplyToProducer(ConnectionFactory factory) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    String replyQueue;

    try {
        connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();

        replyQueue = "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to";
        AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties
                .Builder()
                .replyTo(replyQueue)
                .build();
        String message = "Hello World";

        final BlockingQueue<String> response = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent x'" + message + "'");

        channel.basicConsume(replyQueue, true, new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                response.offer(new String(body, "UTF-8"));
            }
        });
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE, props, message.getBytes());

        System.out.println(response.take());
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (channel != null)
                channel.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException _ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, with your answer I solved my problem in C# Client. Thank you very much.